# Gameplay tag synonym for game-design

Tags: discussion, questions, tags

I've just gained the privilege edit synonyms (yipeeh!), this gave me an excuse to browse around the synonyms database to see what was going on in there.

Turns out, I'm very surprised that [gameplay](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameplay) is a synonym for [game-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design).

To me gameplay *programming* at least should be distinguished from game design. Of course the limit is blurry between the two, but in the industry those are often different professions.

So should we have a [gameplay-programming](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameplay-programming) tag, and if yes, should [gameplay](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameplay) be a synonym for it?

Or am I just nitpicking?

**EDIT**

In answer to Tetrad's comment, to illustrate my point, here are some questions that would be *more* about [gameplay-programming](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameplay-programming), more implementation-oriented:

- [How to develop RPG Damage Formulas?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14309/how-to-develop-rpg-damage-formulas)
- [Profanity filter for an MMO chat](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15109/profanity-filter-for-an-mmo-chat)
- [Have any video game designs used non-uniform random numbers in interesting ways?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/824/have-any-video-game-designs-used-non-uniform-random-numbers-in-interesting-ways)
- [Is there a way to procedurally generate the history of a world?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/is-there-a-way-to-procedurally-generate-the-history-of-a-world)

And some that would be *more* about [game-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design), so more creative-process-oriented:

- [How do you prevent inflation in a virtual economy?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/how-do-you-prevent-inflation-in-a-virtual-economy)
- [What is the purpose of having lives?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14918/what-is-the-purpose-of-having-lives)
- [Are there many games involving the manipulation of water?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/are-there-many-games-involving-the-manipulation-of-water)
- [How do you come up with ideas for new games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/how-do-you-come-up-with-ideas-for-new-games)

Comment: Gameplay-programming feels to broad since we have some pretty good specific tags - see Jumping, Physics, Input, Collision Detection, AI, etc.

Comment: Give me examples of questions that would have [tag:gameplay-programming] tag

Comment: Well they'll necessary be made up, but it could be job related: What skills are employers waiting from gameplay programmers? Or more technical: Should gameplay code be programmed preferably in script, or C++?

Comment: I meant examples of questions that are currently on the site.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll try to find some.

Comment: @Tetrad Here you go

Answer (score 2):

No, because it's not meaningful. I'll draw on your comment in two parts. First, the more trivial part:

> Or more technical: Should gameplay code be programmed preferably in script, or C++?

Gameplay code in script vs C++ is an [architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) question.

Good, that's out of the way. Now for the less trivial part:

> Well they'll necessary be made up, but it could be job related: What skills are employers waiting from gameplay programmers?

*What the heck is a gameplay programmer?* Every programmer working on the game is ultimately programming for the gameplay directly or indirectly, unless you hired a guy only to program the main menu. So, better question: *what kind of game programmer isn't a gameplay programer?*

The only people in the studio who are programming but not programming gameplay are probably the ones programming some custom tools. We've had some people who ask about how to create a level editor for their game, and that typically gets filed under something like [engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) [programming](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming). We generally don't otherwise get asked about that, presumably because whoever's doing that stuff is advanced enough they don't need us. It's just desktop development to a large extent.

That means at the end of the day: basically every programming question we get is gameplay programming, with the exception of a handful. [gameplay-programming](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameplay-programming) might as well just be a synonym of [programming](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming).

Comment: Well sorry to be persistent but gameplay programmer *is* really a job title. I used to be one. Wikipedia also lists it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programmer#Gameplay_programmer. That's to make a distinction with more engine-oriented programmers: graphics, audio, UI, network... Now I'm totally convinced that nobody should restrict himself to gameplay programming, it's very important to keep a broad range of skills. But yeah, gameplay is simply the part of games that is specific to one game's mechanics, and that can't get factorized in a game engine.

Comment: I hadn't considered that. There is actually a line you can draw there. Thanks, now I have something to think about. :)

Comment: Hey, np, I really feel like I'm nitpicking anyway ;) Now you might start to see why this gameplay = game-design thing sounds weird to me. I'm no theorist but to me a game designer and game programmer have the same relationship when creating gameplay than, maybe, an architect and a site foreman when raising buildings. So err... I'd say game design is not gameplay, it's the creative process that leads to it.

Comment: The discussion as to whether or not "gameplay programming" is a discipline aside, I do agree that "gameplay-programming" as a tag is too broad to be useful. I'm not thrilled about "gameplay" or "game-design" either.